# gulp-cli timestamp not displayed

Tags: gulp

Consider the following minimal example:

```
$ yarn init
$ yarn add gulp gulp-cli --dev
```

and a minimal `gulpfile.js` file

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  console.log('Hello World!');
});
```

If I run `./node_modules/gulp-cli/bin/gulp.js` I get the following output

```
[        ] Using gulpfile /tmp/test/gulpfile.js
[        ] Starting 'default'...
Hello World!
[        ] Finished 'default' after 152 μs
```

The timestamps are not displayed in my console. However, if I copy the content of the console and paste it into an editor of my choice, then I can see the timestamps. Hence, my terminmal must be part of the problem. I was wondering how I can debug it. Is there something special about the console output of gulp-cli and the timestamps? I already toggled through several fonts without luck. I also tried as shells bash and zsh. I'm using gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug/feature of the solarized theme. AFAIK the solarized theme won't be fixed and mocha and all the other console writers won't change their behavior just because of one theme.

As a starter have a look [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/656) or just google for gulp and solarized.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the solarized dark theme. It is in fact still an open issue: [Color fix needed?](https://github.com/altercation/solarized/issues/220)

The best fix for this is imo to use the patched version found in [mbadolato/iTerm2-Color-Schemes](https://github.com/mbadolato/iTerm2-Color-Schemes):

- [link to the actual "Solarized Dark - Patched.itermcolors"](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mbadolato/iTerm2-Color-Schemes/master/schemes/Solarized%20Dark%20-%20Patched.itermcolors)